# How to have Polish characters and not affect language of table of contents, etc

Tags: unicode, languages, input-encodings, font-encodings

I am trying to add some Polish characters as part of an acknowledgement section (I am using Texmaker).

I have tried using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{polski}` - the use of the T1 encoding works, but the font changes to that of the old Computer Modern. The use of the babel package also works and retains my font, but the table of contents, list of figures, etc. are all titled in Polish. These are established using the following code:

```
    % Make table of contents
    \newpage
    \pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}
    \tableofcontents

    % list of tables and figures
    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
    \listoftables
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
```

Thanks for any help battling these characters!

EDIT: How this appears in the compiled PDF:
[image]

EDIT 2: It appears now that the TOC remains in Polish after removing all packages and using XeLaTeX instead..

Answer (score 2):

You need nothing special, apart from `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

I want to thank Wojciech Szczęsny for his saves
and Paulo Dybała for his goals. And also all
Polish diacritics ĄĆĘŁŃÓśŹŻąćęłńóśźż.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect the OP is on miktex and hasn't installed the type1 T1 cm fonts

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's a possibility. But the OP also mentions `polski` that, by default uses OT4.

Answer (score 1):

The addition of `\usepackage{lmodern}` in conjunction with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` fixes the poor rasterization of the font, which is the issue I was experiencing. It works well now with these two.

Comment: if you are getting bitmap fonts that means you have an incomplete tex installation without the scalable versions of computer modern, look for cm-super package in miktex or texlive